# Unclear result from Leibniz Integral Rule

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I was trying to answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102644/derivative-of-double-integral-using-leibniz-integral-rule/2102784#2102784) question: $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_{t-\mathrm d1}^t \int_h^t f(s) \,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dh$. I got the accepted answer by hand (using the Leibniz integral rule) but why does Mathematica (and Maple) give the seemingly wrong $\mathrm d_{{1}}f \left( t \right) \color{orange}{-}\int_{t-\mathrm d_{{1}}}^{t}\!f \left( s \right)  \,{\rm d}s=\mathrm d_{{1}}f \left( t \right) \color{orange}{-}F \left( t \right) \color{orange}{+} F \left( t-\mathrm d _{{1}} \right)$ instead of $\mathrm d_{{1}}f \left( t \right) \color{lime}{+}\int_{t-\mathrm d_{{1}}}^{t}\!f \left( s \right)  \,{\rm d}s=\mathrm d_{{1}}f \left( t \right) \color{lime}{+}F \left( t \right) \color{lime}{-} F \left( t-\mathrm d _{{1}} \right)$

The Mathematica code I used is `D[Integrate[Integrate[f[s], {s, h, t}], {h, t - d1, t}], t]`.

Comment: I think *Mathematica* is right, but I have dyslexia.  I could be wrong.

Comment: Until the observed behavior has been confirmed by other users to be a bug, **do not use** the [tag:bugs] tag.

Comment: You can write the integral more simply as `D[Integrate[f[s], {h, t - d1, t}, {s, h, t}], t]` - you don't need to write `Integrate` twice.

Comment: @flinty I had tried that (with the limit variables interchanged) initially but it just gives $d_1 f(t)$ instead of the complete answer.

Comment: @Leponzo No it gives the same answer - are you sure your syntax is correct.

Comment: @flinty Note it is a different computation that is ***supposed*** to be mathematically equivalent.  If you think there's a bug, the form might be important.  In this case, I think it's irrelevant.  I think Leponzo made a mistake in the by-hand check.

Comment: @flinty, your proposal works in 12.1, but goes terribly wrong in version 11. That might be a source of discrepancy.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I can't figure out where my hand calculation and the one at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2102784/185886 are wrong though :(

Comment: Maybbe it's me then.  I'm really bad with signs...What do you get if say $f(x)=e^x$ and work it out two ways, doing the integral and apply the rule?

Comment: Sometimes, to make it easier on myself, I work with a negative-index `Derivative[]`: `D[Integrate[Derivative[-1][f][t] - Derivative[-1][f][h], {h, t - d1, t}], t]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hmm, Mathematica's answer is correct for $e^s$. I'm still figuring out where the general form of the hand solution (with $f(s)$) is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the inner integral result be $F(t)-F(h)$ where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$.
Then break $\int_{t-d1}^{t}F(t)-F(h)\mathrm{dh}$ into $\int_{t-d1}^{t}F(t)\mathrm{dh}$ and $-\int_{t-d1}^{t} F(h)\mathrm{dh}$.

The first integral is just $hF(t)\Big|_{t-d1}^{t}=t F(t)-(t-d1)F(t)=d1 F(t)$.

The second integral is  $-\int_{t-d1}^{t} F(h)\mathrm{dh}=G(t-d1)-G(t)$ where $G$ is the antiderivative of $F$.

Differentiate with respect to  $t$ and we get:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[d1 F(t) +G(t-d1)-G(t)\right]=d1 F'(t)+G'(t-d1)-G'(t) \\
=d1f(t)+\left[F(t-d1)-F(t)\right]=d1f(t)-\left[F(t)-F(t-d1)\right]
$$
I added the brackets for emphasis. Notice how $\left[F(t)-F(t-d1)\right]$ is just $\int_{t-d1}^{t}f(h)\mathrm{dh}$ we set up at the start. Therefore without needing the Leibniz rule at all *Mathematica* is correct in saying:
`D[Integrate[Integrate[f[s], {s, h, t}], {h, t - d1, t}], t] == 
 d1*f[t] - Integrate[f[s], {s, -d1 + t, t}]`

Comment: Slightly modifying the code I posted in an earlier comment: `D[Integrate[Derivative[-1][f][t], {h, t - d1, t}] - Integrate[Derivative[-1][f][h], {h, t - d1, t}], t]`.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't realize `Derivative[-1][f][t]` was a thing. Hopefully seeing it step by step assures Leponzo this is not a bug.

Comment: Thanks! I added my own version of the answer (consistent with Mathematica, Maple, and the Leibniz integral rule) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3694261/185886) (although I still can't pinpoint where the accepted answer there went wrong).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Still didn't get what's wrong :(

Comment: @Leponzo your answer there looks fine to me.

Comment: I think @MichaelE2 was trying to say what's wrong with the accepted answer there.

Comment: @Leponzo does my answer solve your problem?